# Eclipse : How to remove the attached Source which was added to a Jar

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE (Helios Version).
As part of the build path, I have a jar file for this Application, I have attached the source code for this jar file using Attach Source Option.

Please tell me how can I remove this attached source for the jar file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open the .classpath file and delete the source attachment part.

Or in the Build Path control panel, find the jar file and remove the source attachment (it is one of the detailed options there).

Comment: m2e automatically adds the attached source even after you remove it. There seems to be no valid way to use Jadclipse together with m2e. M2e is really great when it does its job. But whenever you want something else it is completely in the way leaving you no option to escape.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two different projects in eclipse that are linked, the best way is to open both of them in eclipse workspace. If you do that, you don't need to "Attach Source..."

If you added the second project as a Source Attachment by mistake, you could try to remove the projects from eclipse workspace and adding them again. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on that jar file >>Build Path >>Configure Build path.
select jar file and remove it or if the file is inside a library, Edit library>>User Libraries>> Remove the jars file and add it again