# Intellij IDEA: How to to remove the attached source added to a Jar?

Tags: intellij-idea

I attached source to a jar in Intellij IDEA.
But now I want to remove the source.

How can I do that?
[There is a post about how to remove source in Eclipse.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443206/eclipse-how-to-remove-the-attached-source-which-was-added-to-a-jar) It dose not work for Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Intellij Idea: click on project structure -> project settings -> Libraries - right click on lib and delete.